Detecting Omega-like forehead wrinkles using opencv
I'm working on a project to detect Omega-like wrinkles in the forehead (a diagnostic feature of depression). I found Hessian filter to be a good way to detect wrinkles based on this paper:

Yap, M. H., Alarifi, J., Ng, C., Batool, N., & Walker, K. (2019). Automated Facial Wrinkles Annotator. In Lecture notes in computer science (pp. 676–680). https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-11018-5_5

I used skimage's hessian filter although not optimal according to this but it's enough in my case.
I applied the following in order:

Gaussian blur.
Hessian filter.
Closing operation.

Here's my code:
image = io.imread("1.jpg", as_gray=True)
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
hessian_image = filters.hessian(image)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(hessian_image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

closing = np.array(np.divide(closing, np.amax(closing)), dtype=np.float64)
closing *= 255
closing = np.uint8(closing)

cv2.imshow("Closing", closing)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Here's an input image:

Here's the output image:

I cannot detect the Omega-like (or rectangle-like) shape using template matching since they tend to vary from one image to another. Do you have any other ideas ?

as always, deep learning

none of the people I know who suffer from depression have such wrinkles. is this limited to age 90+?  just curious. diagnosing people by their facial expression is pretty unethical imho.

@Piglet Check out this paper

May be you can try to use connected components to analyze structures of each pattern. Something like this:
from skimage import measure, filters
import numpy as np

# segments by connected components
segmentation = measure.label(closing)

# finds areas of each connected component, omits background
areas = np.bincount(segmentation.ravel())[1:]
# finds threhsold to remove small components
t = filters.threshold_otsu(areas)
# finds connected component indexes, which areas greater than the threshold
indexes = np.where(areas > t)[0] + 1
# filters out small components
dominant_patterns = np.isin(segmentation, indexes) 

# this is applicable if the image well centered
# forehead center is approximately positioned at image center
# flip image by columns
dominant_patterns_flipped = np.flip(dominant_patterns, axis=1)
# finds intersection with flipped image
omega_like = dominant_patterns * dominant_patterns_flipped

Note: this is applicable if the image is well centered, i.e. forehead is centered in the image, and assumes the existence of vertical symmetry.
This will give you following image:

Now we can profile the image by rows and columns to calculate pixel occurrence per each row and column, by using following function:
import numpy as np

def row_col_profiles(image):
    """
    Returns pixels occurances per row and column
    """
    rows, cols = np.indices((image.shape))
    
    row_lengths = np.bincount(rows.ravel())
    number_of_pixels_on_each_row = np.bincount(rows.ravel(), image.ravel())
    row_profile = number_of_pixels_on_each_row / row_lengths

    col_lengths = np.bincount(cols.ravel())
    number_of_pixels_on_each_col = np.bincount(cols.ravel(), image.ravel())
    col_profile = number_of_pixels_on_each_col / col_lengths

    return row_profile, col_profile

row_profile, col_profile = row_col_profiles(omega_like)

You can plot that profiles like this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10, 5))
axes[0].plot(row_profile)
axes[0].set_title("Horizontal Line Profile")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Row Index")
axes[0].set_ylabel("Bright Pixel Occurance")
axes[0].grid()
axes[1].plot(col_profile)
axes[1].set_title("Vertical Line Profile")
axes[1].set_xlabel("Column Index")
axes[1].set_ylabel("Bright Pixel Occurance")
axes[1].grid()

You will get something like this:

To check whether we have omega-like pattern we can take some thresholds from that profiles, for example 0.2, and also to check at least we have 2 peaks at relatively same level in vertical profile (I've used -10% of maximum).
is_omega_like = row_profile.max()>=0.2 and col_profile.max()>=0.2 and len(np.where(col_profile>col_profile.max()*0.9)[0])>=2

You can also try to measure some properties and find some reasonable threshold on connected components. Please check out the documentation.

Impressive! Since I'm new to skimage, can you suggest some useful properties in my case?

Sure, you can try Hu moments. They are scale, rotation and translation invariant 7 features. To do so either you can directly call on each separate segment this way measure.moments_hu(segment) or on all segments like this: measure.regionprops_table(segmentation, properties=('moments_hu', )). From the last one you can create pandas dataframe. It seems you don't have labeled data, so after calculating Hu moments on all images and all connected components, then you can try to use some unsupervised learning to cluster together the common ones. May be omega-like patterns will cluster together.

I only have 4 images that have Omega-like patterns, too little for a learning algorithm. I might benefit from data augmentation but even with that, I have no Omega-like test data to test my model.

In that case you may try to find some reasonable thresholds manually. I mean you can sweep by the features of your choice and find the best thresholds, which will separate Omega-like from others.
